# How to exit multipage Window 8 PhoneGap app after signout

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have an app with a seperate login and a landing page.

"backbutton" event gets attached when landing page is loaded

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);
```

and "backbutton" event gets removed when login page is loaded

```
document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);
```

This is done so that when app is loaded for the first time with login page, user can press backbutton to exit the app and when user is in landing page my code logic could work and it works well.

But the problem is that when I login to the app, landing page gets loaded and after signout it again takes to the login page, now when user press backbutton, App do not get exit and redirect to the landing page and as user is not authenticated app again redirects to the login page.

How can I exit app in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the app logic slightly and take advantage of this function [NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you are doing this for windows phone.

Comment: Yes, http://jesseliberty.com/2011/07/13/removing-the-backstack-entry-in-windows-phone/ see this for a tutorial